# Unable to Watch Live Data on Extended Events Session

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, extended-events

I am running SQL Server 2014 Developer Edition on my PC.  I am trying to view the data in the system_health session.  In SSMS, I have connected to the database, expanded the server / Management / Extended Events / Sessions.  I see AlwaysON_health (stopped) and system_health (running).

When I right-click on the system_health session, I get the following error:

> The storage failed to initialize using the provided parameters. (Microsoft.SqlServer.XEventStorage)
>      The Extended Events session named "system_health" could not be found. Make sure the session exists and is started. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 25728)

I expand system_health and see the targets package0.event_file and package0.ring_buffer.  If I right-click either target and choose "View Target Data", I get this error:

> The storage failed to initialize using the provided parameters. (Microsoft.SqlServer.XEventStorage)
>   Cannot view the function 'fn_MSXe_read_event_stream', because it does not exist or you do not have permission. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 15151)

The function does exist.  I can run it:

```
select * from fn_MSXe_read_event_stream('system_health', 0);
```

When I do, I get this error:

```
Msg 25728, Level 16, State 10, Line 6
The Extended Events session named "system_health" could not be found. Make  sure the session exists and is started.
```

I know the system_health session is there.  I see in in the list of sessions:

```
select * from sys.dm_xe_sessions

address name       name
------------------ ------------- 
0x00000001FF6510C1 system_health
```

I have tried this with my own custom event sessions.  I can't watch the live data on them, either.

I can query the system_health ring buffer target data from `sys.dm_xe_session_targets`.

Why can't I watch live data for any extended events session?

(Note that there is a [Microsoft feedback item](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32897356-cannot-open-extended-event-when-default-database-n) for this issue.)

Comment: Can you test this on another instance (using the same copy of SSMS), or on this instance from a different copy of SSMS (e.g. from another machine)? Did you try with both windows authentication and sa? Sounds like a problem with the instance, but always good to rule out combinations.

Comment: I found the answer.  My login's default database was set to the one I usually use instead of `master`.  Setting my default database back to `master` resolved the error.

Comment: That seems odd, if you right-click the session in Object Explorer, SQL Server should know where to find it, regardless of your default database.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Yes, I agree!  SSMS should know how to connect to the event session regardless of my default database.  I linked a Microsoft Connect item in my question, should anyone want to vote or comment on it.

Comment: What login are you using? Windows auth or SQL auth? What role(s) are they in?

Comment: I am using a Windows login that is mapped to public and sysadmin.

Comment: You should add that info as another comment on the Connect item, as that is probably not the scenario they tested.

Comment: Good idea.  I can duplicate it with both SQL and Windows logins.  It's all about the default database assigned to the login.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found the problem.  My login had a different default database than the `master` database.  When I changed my default database to `master`, the error went away, and I was able to Watch Live Data on the extended event sessions.

To change the default database, in SSMS, I expanded the server, Security, Logins.  I right-clicked on my user credentials. On the Login Properties page for my user, I changed "Default database" to `master`.  The error went away when I closed and reopened the connection in the SSMS Object Explorer.

**EDIT 2018-12-11**

On the [feedback link for this issue](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32897356-cannot-open-extended-event-when-default-database-n), Karl Fasick posted a likely solution:

> Object Explorer isn't connected to the master database...
>   To fix - disconnect Object Explorer - Reconnect, but go to Connection
>   Properties and explicitly choose master.

Comment: There's a Connect item for this EXACT bug. MS closed it as 'could not reproduce': 

https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/893993/watch-live-data-for-extended-events-causes-the-storage-failed-to-initialize-using-the-provided-parameters-microsoft-sqlserver-xeventstorage-in-sql-2014

Please vote that up if you got here the same way I did (googling on the error - in my case against a 2016 instance).

Comment: New link: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32897356-cannot-open-extended-event-when-default-database-n

Comment: Can confirm that disconnecting and reconnecting, with `master` set as the database under Options > Connection Properties in the connection dialog, was sufficient for me to view the event_file data.  This was with a login that does not have `master` set as the default database.  So no need to change the default database, just ensure you're connecting to `master` when you first log in.